# webforms Enable link if user has access to directory from web.config allowed roles

Tags: webforms, web-config

I have a web form application that has the location path security on it, this works fine.

I have a link to the path on the main page, but I want to make it invisible in the code behind if they do not have security to the folder.

I tried a few things such as:

```
System.Security.AccessControl.DirectorySecurity ds = Directory.GetAccessControl(string.Format("{0}/{1}",HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath, adminFolder));
```

and it returns true as I have access I believe that is due to .NET handeling the security.

I thought about adding the security groups to a key, and just checking if the user is in one of the roles but cannot seem to find how to add a key to the allowed roles.

Here is my web config section which shows the roles1 that can access the folder:

```
<location path="App_Admin">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="role1,role2,role3,role4"/>
        <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

Any help is appreciated on the best way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the SiteMap and security nodes. Have you tried that? 
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178429(v=vs.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178429%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). Read this article. When you see ,Create a Site Map and Enable Security Trimming , they talk about toggling visibility depending on your roles.